# Accessing data field in Node gives me undefined

Tags: node.js

Whenever I try to access a data field, i get an "undefined" log, even though the array seems to print just fine.

```
const users = [];

app.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('users', {
        ListOfNames: users,
        pageTitle: 'active users'
    });
    console.log(users);
    for (let user in users) {
        console.log(user.userName);
    }  
});

app.post('/add-user', function(req, res, next) {
    users.push({ userName: req.body.user });
});
```

Output:

```
[ { userName: '1' },

  { userName: '12' },

  { userName: '123' },

  { userName: '1234' } ]

undefined

undefined

undefined

undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (let user in users)` should be `for (let user of users)`.

`for/in` iterates over object keys, and is typically used with objects.

```
let obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
for (let key in obj) { console.log(key) } // a, b, c
```

`for/of` iterates over iterable values and is typically used with arrays.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
for (let val of arr) { console.log(val) } // 1, 2, 3
```